# Should database constraints map to the business logic

Tags: database, validation, business-logic, unique-constraint

The database has a unique constraint index on the users NAME field.

The business service checks via

```
service.GetUser(userName);
```

to see whether a user name already exists. Because of this logic in the service there can never be inserted duplicate names. I do not catch exceptions for a `SqlException` with Number = 2627 which is for unique constraint violations.

So why would I put a unique constraint on the NAME field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because of this logic in the service there can never be inserted duplicate names, so WHY should I put on the NAME field a unique constraint?

Because there's no other good way to guarantee that, for the entire lifetime of the database, no application adds data except through that service.

Every dbms that I'm familiar with includes a command-line interface, a graphical interface, and a bulk loader. That makes *at least* three applications that can be used to modify data without going through service.GetUser().

Answer (score 3):

You should put as much business logic at the data layer as you possibly can.  Relationships, uniqueness, length, min length, value limitations, whatever you can.

Do not trust an application to put it in correctly, users of your data will try to break it in any way they can.  I personally think it is better to send 500's on bad data than to accept it and fix later, although some people will tell you otherwise, as it is a very contentious issue.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the UNIQUE constraint at the database layer ensures that no duplicate names will occur no matter where the point of entry of the insert (or update) originates. For example, if you leave it to the application layer to ensure unique names, what happens if someone inserts a row directly from the command line, or a batch script outside the scope of the application?

IMO, it's better to keep this unique constraint behavior at the database layer.